# Does Rust code, statically linked to a C program, gain any beneficial safety properties as a result?

Tags: c, rust, type-safety, memory-safety

Inspired by Carol Goulding's [talk](https://github.com/carols10cents/rust-out-your-c-talk) on "Rust Out Your C" and an article I [read](https://jneem.github.io/nnnoiseless/) on porting C to Rust function by function.

If I have a program consisting of 3 functions called one after another:

1 (C) --> 2 (C) --> 3 (C)

And replace the second function as a statically linked, Rust function so the flow becomes:

1 (C) --> 2 (**R**) --> 3 (C)

Is the code in function 2, now memory and / or type safe? Does it gain any additional, beneficial properties in terms of safety?

Answer (score 3):

Yes. And no. It depends.

1. First of, the C code in functions 1 and 3 will not be affected in any way, and will be just as unsafe (per Rust's definition as unsafe) as any C.
2. The code in function 2 will however benefit from Rust safety. Its implementation can be considered safer.

   However, you'll need some glue between your C and Rust. Rust safety mostly come from its type system, and C type system is quite poor in comparison. You'll need to properly call your Rust function from your C function and C function from your Rust function. C is mostly unaware of Rust, so this needs to be done on the Rust side. While there are tools and crates to help with FFI, you always have to assume at some point that the C is correct, as a bug in the C could manifest even in (safe) Rust. Moreover calling a C function from Rust always requires `unsafe`, and a Rust function called from C will often have some `unsafe` too. FFI is easy to get wrong: Wrong size of parameters, bad alignments, bad ABI, use of freed memory are all more likely at a language barrier and are all very unsafe.

Comment: To follow up on this, what if I had the following structure, 1 (C) --> 2 (R) --> 3 (R) --> 4 (R) --> 5 (C)? Does function 3 now have the opportunity to become 'safe'?

Comment: Per Rust definition of safe, 2, 3 and 4 can all be safe (as in, not be annotated with `unsafe`). 4 will have to use the `unsafe` keyword to call 5, but doesn't need to be annotated with `unsafe` itself. With a broader definition, any program that has anything unsafe can be unsafe: UBs are contaminating, and can manifest anywhere, even outside of the `unsafe` block that created them. Therefore, the whole program is safe only if 2 and 4 implement their FFI properly and 1 and 5 are also correct.

Comment: I will object to bullet point 2: The *only* parts of the Rust code that are indeed safe are those internal to the function, that do not - directly or indirectly - alias data from the C code. Everything else just inherits all of C's unsafety. The system, as a whole, is no more safe than it was before.

Comment: @IInspectable have you read the “However” part of bullet point 2?

Comment: To summarize: The Rust part by itself is likely safer than the C part, but the border between C and Rust is likely to be less safe than even a pure C program. The overall effect on the program is therefore hard to judge.

Comment: I have, but it remains very vague. Sure, we know that C's type system is less elaborate than Rust's. Yet the points you explicitly call out merely refer to bugs in your Rust's FFI implementation. That is a solvable issue. The inherent unsafety due to the inability to enforce the C implementation's promised guarantees at the interface are far more relevant. And unsolvable.

Comment: @IInspectable I've added “you always have to assume at some point that the C is correct, *as a bug in the C could manifest even in (safe) Rust*” (italics new, normal old). Is that better?

Comment: It's not just genuine bugs, that jeopardize Rust's safety guarantees. Even 100% correct C code can take the whole system down. There's just no way to express things like `Sync` or `&mut` at the FFI. I guess I'm just a proponent of the unpopular idea, that *gradually* moving to Rust doesn't buy you anything. Unless you can switch an entire isolated component (like a process) to Rust, Rust's safety guarantees aren't.

Answer (score 0):

No, being embedded in C code doesn't make your code safe. You may gain lifetime checking in the Rust section, but only if the entry and exits are correctly annotated; e.g. if your code returns an owned reference, but C code expected it to be borrowed, you still have a memory leak. Rust code itself may also be unsafe; the Rust compiler has tools to help you track memory and types more strictly than a C compiler, but it doesn't force you to use those tools. It just makes it more awkward to write risky code to encourage safe code.